# How to get information on by just using ID in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the the employee id to notice if they are terminated to ignore their count and keep only those who are Active this is what I have:

```
Emp_ID     Status    Manager_ID    Employee_count
  1        Active        3                 0
  2        Active        3                 0
  3        Active        5                 3 
  4        Termed        3                 0
  5        Termed        -                 1
```

And this is what I want:

```
Emp_ID     Status     Manager_ID     Employee_count
   1       Active         3                0
   2       Active         3                0 
   3       Active         5                2
   4       Termed         3                0
   5       Active         -                1
```

The current code below is what I have and what I am trying to build off of to go from the first table to the second table displayed and I am a little lost.

```
#Creates and stores dictionary that takes the last row of each id and takes the status then fills the rest of the history with that.

status_dict = df.groupby('Emp_ID').agg({'Status':'last'}).to_dict()['Status']
df['Status'] = df['Emp_ID'].apply(lambda x: status_dict[x])

#Count the unique emp_ID thne map the counts to Emp_ID    

count = df['Emp_ID'].groupby(df['Manager_ID'].astype(str)).nunique()
df['Status'] == df['Emp_ID'].astype(str).map(count).fillna(0,downcast='infer')
```

Comment: You have lots of syntax errors (missing quotes and brackets) in your code. Please post valid code.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly is the input?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I was rushing when I created it, I have corrected those mistakes

Comment: @mozway the input is the code provided so far that is what I have and I am looking to build off that to if possible to get the outputted table displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `Manager_ID` to create a lookup series that will map `Emp_ID`:

```py
s_mng_cnt = df[df["Status"]!="Termed"].groupby("Manager_ID")["Employee_count"].count()
df["Employee_count"] = df["Emp_ID"].astype(str).map(s_mng_cnt).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Emp_ID  Status Manager_ID  Employee_count
0       1  Active          3               0
1       2  Active          3               0
2       3  Active          5               2
3       4  Termed          3               0
4       5  Termed          -               1
```

Edit: regarding the change of `Status` from "Termed" to "Active" for employees that are listed as managers of other employees:

```
df.loc[df["Emp_ID"].astype(str).isin(df['Manager_ID']),'Status'] = "Active"
```